# How to select an option from javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I select the `<select>` tag option from the javascript/Angularjs backend.

Hint: I actually get data from API service, then I fill into a form to make them available for edit. Assume the gender is Male, how can I make the `<select>` tage becomes Male as it is in databse. So user can update it to Female for example.

Here is my codes:

```js
  $scope.Gender = [
    { GenderID: "Mmale", name: "Mmale" },
    { GenderID: "Female", name: "Female" }
    ];

//Assigning data to select tag. But this did not work for me:
$scope.Gender.name = $scope.users[id].Gender;
$scope.Gender.GenderID = $scope.users[id].Gender;
```

```html
 <select class="form-control" name="Gender" ng-model="GenderID" ng-options="g.GenderID as g.name for g in Gender" required style="width:98px; color:gray">
                        <option value="" style="" >Gender?</option>
                    </select>
<input type="button" value="SelectMale()">
```

Comment: Its not clear what you asking, do you want to initiate start value? what is the purpose of input field?

Comment: Is just demo for an event ..

Comment: Could you please be more precise on what you are asking, and what type of solution do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
$scope.selectMale = function() {
    $scope.GenderId = "Mmale"; 
}
```

[Working plunke](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENKuhIjsOulXGEdosva6?p=preview)r.

Comment: no. Please consider that options are rendered from the ng-options

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working plunker. I don't understand what  the problem is.

Comment: I had a problem using Plunker, please ignore that. By the way, I updated my post and made it more clear, can you please try solving it now ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see the selected value you can use **ng-change** write the code as:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Gender" ng-model="GenderID" ng-options="g.GenderID as g.name for g in Gender" ng-change="Selectmale(g.GenderID)" required style="width:98px; color:gray"> 
  <option value="" style="" ></option>
</select>

$scope.Selectmale=function(genderId){
  console.log(genderId) //this will return the current genderId
}
```

Comment: no that is not what I want, anyway, thank you for reply. Please see review my post again because I updated it to be more clear..